Spire XLS - create excel without repeating Key columns
I have the following model with the key columns Id and Name.
I would like to create an excel sheet where you only print these key columns once.
Id  Name        Date                            Location
1   John Doe    01/01/2022                      London
1   John Doe    02/01/2022                      Paris
1   John Doe    03/01/2022                      Milan

I want to achieve this:
Id  Name        Date                            Location
1   John Doe    01/01/2022                      London
                02/01/2022                      Paris
                03/01/2022                      Milan

Is this possible to achieve?
